# Will what I send in on MIDI In come out through (MIDI over) USB?

Tags: midi, midi-controller-keyboard

I am playing a church organ installed as software on my PC. I play it from my digital piano (Kawi CS10) connected through USB to the PC, and it works fine. Now I want to add a pedalboard (https://www.danmusikk.no/studiologic-mp117-bass-pedal) to play the bass notes with my feet. The pedal board only have 5pin MIDI Out. The piano have both MIDI In/Thru/Out and USB. If I connect the pedals to MIDI In on the piano, will those midi signals be transmitted over the USB from the Piano and end up on the PC? They will of course have to send on different Midi channels. If not, will connecting the pedals directly to the computer via a MDI-to-USB adaptor(https://www.danmusikk.no/midiplus-midilink-mini-1x1-usb-midi-interface) work? The PC will then have two MIDI devices playing on separate USB ports?

Comment: Have you asked Kawai customer support? I think they would know better than anyone here

Answer (score 2):

The in/out/through usually has a standard config.

- *In* goes to the piano's voices,
- *Out* goes to 'a. n. other device' from the piano keyboard.
- *Through* goes from the *in* to the *through*.

Sometimes *through* can be configured as an extra *out* &/or an extra *in*, but none of those will send an external source to your computer, so you need the extra Midi adapter.

The manual should confirm this, but tbh I didn't check;)

Comment: I guess another way to put my question is "Does the piano's USB port include a MIDI-Thru functionality, i.e. passing out what comes in on the 5pin MIDI-In?" I find it difficult to clarify the connection between the 5pin MIDI-ports and the USB-port, both in the documentation and on Google. BTW, I was wrong - my piano has no Thru port, only Midi In and Out. But my question still remains.

Comment: In & Out are in & out to/from the piano keyboard itself - there is no onward transmission normally.